# What is "grub" command/program? Does it tweak GRUB2 as well or only GRUB legacy

Tags: grub2, grub-legacy

From my terminal:

```
heer@heer-Latitude-D620:~$ grub --help
The program 'grub' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install grub
heer@heer-Latitude-D620:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**GRUB** (package name: `grub`)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/grub/), also known as **GRand Unified Bootloader (Legacy version)** is the predecessor of [**GRUB2 (package name: `grub-pc`)**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/grub-pc/), also known as **GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)**. So, `grub` it doesn't tweak with nothing GRUB2, but replaces GRUB2:

```
$ sudo apt-get install grub
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  grub-legacy-doc mdadm
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub2-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  grub
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Since with version 9.10 of Ubuntu, this has used GRUB 2 as the default boot loader for clean installs (prior to this it was GRUB).

See which are some differences here:

- [Differences between GRUB, GRUB2 and BURG](https://askubuntu.com/q/19605/147044)
- [GRUB vs GRUB 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Improvements)

Answer (score 0):

- GRUB is the boot loader (and Ubuntu loader) program which loads Ubuntu from the disk to the Memory to be run. So, yes, Such a program is essential to have Ubuntu and it is Grub by default. But there are other bootloader too, such as LILO (LInux LOader) and recent BURG.
- To learn Grub command, You can use the Grub manual [**here**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grub).
- Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the **GRUB2/BURG** settings and menu entries.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
  ```