# Error: Package 'grub-legacy' has no installation candidate!

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, package-management, virtualbox

I'm trying to install grub-legacy package on Ubuntu virtual box but I keep getting this error:

```
Package grub-legacy is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
grub-coreboot grub2-common grub-pc grub-ieee1275 grub-efi-ia32
grub-efi-amd64

E: Package 'grub-legacy' has no installation candidate
```

Why I got this error?
If I replace it with one of the following packages for example grub-pc, is that going to make any difference ?

Comment: I always use `grub-efi-amd64` (since Ubuntu 18.04) and I had no problem with that.  But it depends on whether your PC supports efi or old BIOS.  [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19605/differences-between-grub-grub2-and-burg) may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB Legacy is in maintenance mode and new features are only accepted in GRUB 2 (*grub-pc* package). To install grub-pc open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install grub-pc
```

This package contains a version of GRUB that has been built for use with traditional PC/BIOS architecture.